# selecting radio buttons using selenium webdriver in clojure

Tags: selenium-webdriver, clojure

I want to know how you select `radio buttons` using `Selenium Webdriver`?

I have used `find-element` and `select`, But I think I am not knowing the proper way to use them.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and any specific error messages you are getting or why the code isn't meeting your requirements. [ask]

Comment: @JeffC I have posted

Comment: That's the HTML... please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [`click`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#click) function from [`clj WebDriver`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation) which would work to select radio button as :-

```
(click "css locator for radio button")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but What I tell you for this?? I have already given you link attached with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a range of functions documented in [Taxi API](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation). Choose whichever suits you best.

- [`select`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#select)
- [`select-all`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#select-all)
- [`select-by-index`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#select-by-index)
- [`select-by-text`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#select-by-text)
- [`select-by-value`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#select-by-value)
- [`select-option`](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#select-option)

Comment: Can you tell me for this code? I have tried select but having an error